# How to update SQLite database in a phonegap/cordova setup without uninstalling app?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, cordova

I have an Android and iOS app that uses a prepopulated SQLite database to implement certain logic. The problem is that when I change any value inside db or update its schema, the app has to be manually reinstalled or else it does not reflect any changes from the db.

Is there a way from which I can install the new db from the apk instead of the app using the existing one?

I have not used any sync module to update values inside app nor do I enter any value inside the db. So, basically, I only wish to access values

Comment: what do you mean when you say install new db, drop all tables or reinitialize all db?

Comment: i meant make the app use the updated db file from the apk instead of the existing one